# Loading modified RSL's without clearing cache

Tags: load, rsl

the previous versions of my RSL's are cached in the flash player and the modified Rsl does not get loaded when i run my application. Can anyone give me a solution to load the modified RSL without clearing the flash player cache?

BJ

Answer (score 1):

I think he means is that it is cached (it's in the browser, but no matter). It's my problem as well, since I have several customers who need the same product, but an swc contains the opening text for each. So I separated that from the main swf to an swc, thinking that I can change it whenever I like without building the whole project for every customer. But if a certain customer's text needs to be updated, I copy the new swf file, but it's already cached by the browser and I can't expect users to clear their browser cache...

Answer (score 0):

I think only adobe "signed" RSLs are stored in Flash Player cache, all the ones compiled by punny humans are "unsigned" and go straight to browser cache...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a digest to your RSL in order to solve this problem,
take a look at this:
[link text](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf674ba-7ff6.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ad2)